# Caching external build script for offline use

Tags: gradle

I want to externalize generic parts of my large build file in order to share them between projects. The easiest option in my view is to put the Gradle code into new build files and storing them on the server. Then I can include them with "apply from:".

This has the disadvantage that the build fails if there is no internet connection.

How would you solve this problem? Can I make Gradle cache the online build scripts?

Thanks for sharing your thoughts on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caching of script plugins will be provided in a future version of Gradle. In the meantime, if you need offline support, your best option is to write a binary plugin (class implementing `org.gradle.api.Plugin`), package it up as a Jar, publish it to a repository, and specify it as a `classpath` dependency in the `buildscript` section of any build that wishes to use the plugin. For more information, see the [Writing Custom Plugins](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html#custom_plugins) chapter in the Gradle user guide.

Comment: @Peter, is this available yet in gradle 1.11 or newer?

Comment: No it isn't available yet.

Comment: Nearly 4 years later, any plans for this? Or should we just use @kageiit's plugin?

Comment: @swooby [Caching of script plugins is now available in Gradle 4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46104883/531762).

Answer (score 6):

I made a plugin to make this possible now: https://github.com/kageiit/gradle-url-cache-plugin

Answer (score 0):

### This feature is available in Gradle 4.2-rc-1 and later

The [release notes](https://docs.gradle.org/4.2-rc-1/release-notes.html) for this version say that script plugins over HTTP(S) are now cached and available offline.

> **Better support for script plugins loaded via HTTP**
>
> Script plugins are applied to Gradle settings or projects via the `apply from: 'URL'` syntax. Support for http:// and https:// URLs has been improved in this release:
>
> - HTTP script plugins are cached for `--offline` use.
> - Download of HTTP script plugins honours proxy authentication settings.